# Узнать MAC-адрес устройства, подключенного к WiFi-роутеру

Tags: ip, mac, роутер

Сложилось впечатление, что это какая-то сугубо конфиденциальная информация, скрываемая от пользователя. Подключил микроплату через сетевой кабель к WiFi-роутеру. На плате LED-индикаторы мигают соответствующим образом, на роутере отображается индикатор подключения. В логах роутера отображается, что к интерфейсу FastEthernet0/4 есть подключение. Во-первых, DHCP не назначает IP моему устройству, хотя вчера один раз он это сделал и как это произошло я не понимаю. Я хочу настроить вручную через PUTTY, но я не могу узнать MAC-адрес микроплаты. Роутер: ZyXEL

Comment: Не совсем понимаю чего Вы хотите сделать узнав mac-адрес, но можно посмотреть все mac-адреса на порту коммутатора, для этого поищите спецификации для него. Или просто подключите плату к ПК (например) и при помощи wireshark/tcpdump посмотрите сетевую активность на порту ПК.

Comment: Назначить IP по известному mac, это возможно?

Comment: на linux, который в основе большинства современных прошивок роутеров, назначать конкретный ip конкретному mac возможно. А вот добавили ли такую опцию в настройки конкретного роутера зависит не только от производителя, но и от модели и даже от версии прошивки. Что касается узнавания mac то мало какие роутеры это могут показать пока сами не выдадут ip. Микротики вроде умеют показывать FDB

Comment: Проблема в том что моя микроплата получает IP только иногда , в остальных случаях она как будто не действует

Comment: Дык, дебажить надо. Если б предо мной встала такая проблема, я б подключил контроллер к ПК, поднял какой-то простой `dhcpd` и с помощью  `wireshark/tcpdump` смотрел как общаются плата и ПК основываясь на rfc 2131. Такие дела :)